# How to display formatted JSON in VSCode Extension Webview

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm developing extension for VSCode and need to display formatted JSON **inside** a Webview panel. It should also be collapsable.

How do I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: A plain editor for the JSON content is not good enough? It would support your requirements out of the box.

Comment: @MikeLischke, Thanks for reply. Monaco Editor is the editor VSCode used. But how do I access it from within WebViewPanel? Built-in monaco editor, not include it externally.

Comment: It's not possible to directly access the underlying Monaco instances.